# Unable to use prefab login controls in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the Login box from the toolbox in visual studio. All the formats and such are already built-in, like the login boxes and password box, etc. But for some reason, I cannot get  `if (Convert.ToInt32(obj) != 0)` to return anything but 0, unless I manually replace the @username and @password with 123 and 5551212 into the SQL string.

```
protected void Login_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon))
    {
        string UserName = Login.UserName;
        string Password = Login.Password;

        str = "select count(*) from users where username=@username and userpassword=@userpassword";
        com = new MySqlCommand(str, con);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
        com.Parameters.Add("@userpassword", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            obj = com.ExecuteScalar();

            if (Convert.ToInt32(obj) != 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Login.PasswordRequiredErrorMessage = "invalid user name and password";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Since

```
obj = com.ExecuteScalar();
       if (Convert.ToInt32(obj) != 0)
```

Always gives me an obj of 0, I can never log in. But, as I said above, if I change the variables in the SQL string to the correct numbers for login and password, count is returned as 1, and then I can login.

Help appreciated! I'm not sure what Im missing. Using MySQL, or more specifically, MariaDB.

Comment: Please format your code consistently.

Comment: Um. Huh? I've been accused of alot of things, but messy code hasn't been one of them.

Comment: This is no _accusation_, only a benevolent suggestion. Your code is _not_ messy. Only formatting (indentation) is _inconsistent_, and therefore less easy to read then it should be. Fix it.